# tangent line with python

Tags: python, geometry, line

Could some one help me to calculate tangent line angle to curve.
my curve is defined

```
x=0.          0.02743333  0.05486667  0.0823      0.10973333  0.13716667
  0.1646      0.19203333  0.21946667  0.2469      0.27433333  0.30176667
  0.3292      0.35663333  0.38406667  0.4115

y=
0.0,                 0.041685454222222217, 0.078408362666666648, 0.11047814399999997, 
0.13820421688888887, 0.16189599999999998,  0.18186291199999996,  0.19841437155555552,  
0.21185979733333329, 0.22250860799999994,  0.23067022222222222,  0.23665405866666664,  
0.24076953599999995, 0.24332607288888886,  0.244633088,          0.24499999999999986
```

I would need to know the angle between tangent line and x-axis at 0,0

I just don't understand how to do this.

Comment: [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You'll need to fit a polynomial to the data, and differentiate to find the tangent.

Comment: You need to know the slope at 0,0... And you can get that using the first two points of the series

Comment: wikipedia: [Tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent), [Slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)

Comment: more or less: `tangent = slope = (y[1] - y[0]) / (x[1] - x[0])`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not clear what you mean with a curve. 
If your x/y coordinates define a polygon then, it is not a big deal. 
But if they define a cubic curve like BSplines, the things get complicated. 
I assume, you need the angle of the tangent to a polygon.

The easiest way to achive that, is to compute the slope for all lines through the point (0,0) and each of your coordinates. 
`s=(y[i]-0)/(x[i]-0) = y[i]/x[i]`

Then you take the max slope whitch is the slope of the tangent. All other lines will intersect the curve because their slope is less than the tangents slope. (Draw yourself a polygon and try it. ;-) )

Now you perform the inverse tangens `tan⁻¹(max slope)` of the maximal slope and you'll get the angle.